# How to construct servlet URL

Tags: java, servlets

Right now I have a servlet URL as below in one of my stored procedure , which is a working one.

URL: http://server600.ctm.com/batch/shyamServletClass?parameter= || Incoming;

The above points to the servlet calss EAR which deployed in server600.ctm.com, but I need to modify the URL in scuh a way that it should point to my local system EAR. (That means the code which is there in (C://code/workspace/batch/shyamServletClass)

Suppose my IP Address is 172.16.61.208, how should I change it?

Comment: What help are you looking for? why can't you replace the URL domain name with your IP address specified?

Comment: Are you sure you want the `.class` file? Or you want to refer to the servlet in localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

Let it point to `http://localhost` instead of `http://server600.ctm.com`.

Note that this only works when the caller and the servlet runs at physically the same server machine.